# How to make selenium click partial link text by match in dict

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary

I have a dict with values i need to click in a page to download files.

How can i make selenium `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(` dict element `).click`

I am using the code bellow, but i repeat it for many elements and its slowing the code.

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('ASD!').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    return
try:
     driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('QWE#').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
     return
```

my dict:

```
dict = {
  "ASD!",
  "QWE#"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no reason to use a dict here you could just use a list. What you have there is a set since there is no key/value pairs. This code will work for a set or a list.

```
l = ["ASD!", "QWE#"]

for s in l:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(s).click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return
```